# How use Metadata deocde Vec::<EventRecord<Event, H256>>

Tags: events, metadata, frame-system

1. first  get the system eventData `state_getStorage` api
2. now i need to decode the system eventData by metadata

is there some example how to decode it ?
for some reaseon ,only rust worker it  ,thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here are some very detailed examples.

1. [subscribe_all_event](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/master/examples/examples/subscribe_all_events.rs)
2. [subscribe_one_event](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/master/examples/examples/subscribe_one_event.rs)
3. [subscribe_some_event](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/master/examples/examples/subscribe_some_events.rs)